# Select field from table a if it exists, if it doesn't select field from table b

Tags: sql, join

```
SELECT a.amount, CASE When d.name <> NULL Then d.name Else c.name End As 'name'
from a
JOIN b on a.id= b.id
LEFT JOIN c on a.tokenId = c.tokenId 
LEFT JOIN d on a.tokenId  = d.tokenId
```

I'm attempting to select the name from table d if it exists, and if it doesn't, select it from table c. The name field comes back as NULL, however I know they are not null in either of the tables.

Can anyone help me get this solved?

Comment: try it with `d.name IS NOT NULL Then ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the `<>` operator to compare with `null`. Use the `is` operator:

```
SELECT a.amount, CASE When d.name is not null Then d.name Else c.name End As 'name'
```

You can also use the `coalesce` function:

```
SELECT a.amount, coalesce(d.name, c.name) As 'name'
```

Comment: For some reason it's still showing null in the name column... any recommendation on changing the joins?

Comment: @William: Are you sure that there is always a matching record either from the `c` or `d` table? If neither has the token, you will `null` from both. If it should be possible that there is no record from any of them, use whatever value you want instead in the `coalesce` function, for example `coalesce(d.name, c.name, 'n/a')`.

Comment: If I change them to RIGHT OUTER JOINs I see the corresponding names, but not any value before it (such as a.amount).

Comment: @William: That means that you have records in `c` or `d` that doesn't have any corresponding record in `a`.

Comment: Dude, you're so right. I was joining on the wrong column in c and d. Facepalm.

Answer (score 1):

Use COALESCE:

```
SELECT a.amount, COALESCE(d.name,c.name) "name"
from a
JOIN b on a.id= b.id
LEFT JOIN c on a.tokenId = c.tokenId 
LEFT JOIN d on a.tokenId  = d.tokenId
```